# Searchkick Gem Suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some trouble getting the searchkick gem to load suggestions of a field. I've been following a guide but it doesn't seem to work for me.

When I start to type a property name in the text_field, I want the search form to suggest the full `name` of the property in question.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the code in question:

**model**

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick text_start: [:name]

    def search_data
        {
            name: name,
        }
    end
end
```

**controller**

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def autocomplete
    render json: Property.search(params[:term], fields: [{name: :text_start}], limit: 10).map(&:name)
  end
end
```

**search form (in _header partial)**

```
<%= form_tag properties_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, placeholder: "search" %>
    <% end %>
```

**routes**

```
resources :properties do
    collection do
      get :autocomplete
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you ran `Property.reindex` to add the search data?

Comment: @marcbest yep, multiple times! I'm doing that plus restarting my server all the time just to double-check haha